# Unable to update the root password for MySQL — my.cnf is protected

Tags: macos, mysql, xampp

I'm unable to update the root password for MySQL. *On MAC OSX*

my.cnf seems to be protected, even after using `sudo open -t my.cnf` it still doesn't allow saving of the config file.

The message when saving is

> This document could not be autosaved because you don’t have write
>   access privileges to the folder that it’s in.

We had it working and Xampp leaves a blank root password, but after changing it in `phpmyadmin`, and rebooting, we now have no privileges when returning to phpmyadmin.

XAMPP's Status page says the password is set.

We were trying to figure out how to access MySQL in terminal but couldn't work it out.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button if you want to add something to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The password has nothing to do with `my.cnf`.

MySQL has a data dictionary, where user accounts are stored. The default MySQL sysadmin account is named 'root'. There are actually two different ways to reset the root account password in windows:

1. Making a script that gets run at startup using a command line option
2. Setting a command line option that tells MySQL not to implement security at all, which allows you to login, change the password and then restart it

Both methods are documented in step-by-step fashion here:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows

Comment: Someone edited my question - I put *MAC OSX* in the title. Also tagged as such.

Comment: Then use method 2, which works for all versions of mysql.  You start mysql with --skip-grant-tables, then follow the instructions to update the root password.